# Web Component that can request another HTML URL and inject it into it's shadow DOM

Tags: web-component, oembed, native-web-component, lit

I spent some time today with Lit trying to make a simple WebComponent that makes a HTTP GET to a URI, which returns a fully formed HTML document, and I want to inject said HTML document into the WebComponent's shadow DOM; basically this WebComponent acts as a simple proxy for embedding an externally hosted (but trusted) web snippet on my web page. I ran into a few problems:

1. Lit considers all HTML unsafe, so i had to mark it with Lit's `unsafeHTML` directive.
2. Then, I noticed none of the script or link tags in the injected HTML were being followed, so I parsed the incoming HTML as a HtmlDocument, located all the script/link tags, and "re-created" them using `document.createElement(...)` and returned them in my render(). I'm now noticing that images arent showing up either.

I don't like scraping scripts/links and re-creating them and jamming them into my web component anyhow, but I'm curious - what's the right way to approach this syndicating/consuming syndicated HTML pages/fragments?

Is this a solved problem w/ oEmbed already?

Is this simpler to do with a different WebComponent library?

This seems way harder than it should be at this point.

Comment: 1. Is extra protection in Lit, other libraries may or may not have that barrier. 2. Is just how the Web works; I wouldn't trust any library that makes injecting ``<script>`` 'easier', as it opens up XSS attacks

Comment: Thanks! I’m operating in a trusted ecosystem so security isn’t a concern for my use case. I’ll take a look at writing a native web Component.. thanks!

Comment: I wrote that native Web Component for you.... but it still doesn't execute ``<script>`` See: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Answer (score 0):

I think that it has little to do with WebComponents but rather with the HTML5 specs. lit-html [uses `innerHTML` to create elements](https://github.com/lit/lit/blob/main/packages/lit-html/src/lit-html.ts#L826).

[Script elements inserted using innerHTML do not execute when they are inserted](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0)

There are still ways to execute JS but this has little to do with your question.

```js
unsafeHTML(`<img src="triggerError" onerror="alert('BOOM')">`)
```

Regarding the images, it may be a path issue?

This should work:

```js
unsafeHTML(`<img src='http://placehold.it/350x350'>`)
```